# About Lyapunov exponent. Can I say that a smaller Lyapunov exponent (negative) means "better" stability?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, lyapunov-exponents

For a equilibrium position $x_0$ and a perturbed (or with error) one $x_0^\prime:= x_0 + \epsilon_0$. Their distance after time $t$ is $\epsilon_t \approx \epsilon_0  e^{t \lambda(x_0)}$. Can I say that the smaller the $\lambda(x_0)$, the "better" its stability is?

For example, it is obviously that for $\lambda=-2$, $\epsilon_t \approx \epsilon_0 e^{t \lambda}$ will converge to $0$ faster, compared to the $\lambda=-1$ case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks to Dr. Lehmann for adding the tag.

Comment: you can say "faster." To say "better," you must define your performance metric first. E.g., a faster system can be less energy-efficient.

Comment: The claim of exponential behavior is only in general true for a relatively small time interval. The distance can change its monotonicity, from growing to falling or the other way. To get a stable result for the exponent one could consider the average exponent. One could restrict the situation to an equilibrium point, a periodic system with a bounded solution, a periodic cycle.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann Thanks! I wonder if $x_0$ is the unique solution, "the more negative $\lambda(x_0)$, the 'better' the stability" is true?

Comment: Yes, from the point-of-view of keeping towards the steady state. But as Arastas said, if rapid correction in the physical workd is better depends on the circumstances. It can make a physical system rather rigid. On the other hand, one can simulate rigid bodies and their elastic collisions via a mesh of springs with large spring constants

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think my problem is solved.